# How do I refresh @html.Action from a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page that on the left hand side is a menu list of assets, that when you click on an asset then a form appears on the right hand side to edit that asset. I need to be able to refresh the list of assets after an edit of an asset so that any changes in the name appear on the menu list as well.

Here is my page

```
 </head>
    <body>
        <div id="leftHandMenu">
        <h2>assets</h2>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Create Asset", "CreateAsset", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "FormContainer", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
        @Html.Action("Assets")
        </div>
        <div id="FormContainer">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The List of assets in created using the @html.Action("Assets") call. 
Here is the view for the list of assets

```
 @model IList<CasWeb.Models.DataContext.Asset>
 @if (Model != null && Model.Any())
 {
     <ul>
         @foreach (var asset in Model)
         {

             <li> @Ajax.ActionLink(asset.Name, "EditAsset", new { id = asset.Id }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "FormContainer", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }) </li>
         }
     </ul> 
    }else
         {
             <h1> no assets</h1>
         }
```

And here is my Edit Asset View

```
 @using System.Collections
@model CasWeb.Models.DataContext.Asset


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('form').submit(function () {
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#FormContainer').html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <fieldset>

            <legend>Asset</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModelId, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["AssetModels"], "Id", "Model"))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelId)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SizeId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SizeId, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["AssetSizes"], "Id", "Size"))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SizeId)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TypeId, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["AssetTypes"], "Id", "Type"))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeId)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeptId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DeptId, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Depts"], "Id", "Name"))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeptId)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

and here is my Controller

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult Assets()
{
    var assets = _assetRepo.GetAll();
    return PartialView(assets);
}

public PartialViewResult EditAsset(Guid id)
{
    SetUpViewDataForComboBoxes();

    var asset = _assetRepo.Get(id);
    return asset == null
               ? PartialView("NotFound")
               : PartialView("EditAsset", asset);
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult EditAsset(Asset asset)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _assetRepo.Update(asset);
        return PartialView("EditAssetSuccess");
    }

    SetUpViewDataForComboBoxes();

    return PartialView("EditAsset", asset);
}
```

I would like to be able to refresh the assets view in EditAsset post method in the controller after the save, as this is more testable, but from what I can tell I may need to do this in the success call back for the edit form java script submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Edit Assest, use Ajax form and call following method OnSuccess event. You also need to call following method on page load.

```
$.get("/ControllerName/Assets", { random: '@DateTime.Now.Ticks' }, function (response) {
                $("#ListOfAssestDiv").html(response);                
            });
```

For display assest list i mean ( @Html.Action("Assets")) put in another div. So your code become like this

```
 </head>
    <body>
        <div id="leftHandMenu">
        <h2>assets</h2>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Create Asset", "CreateAsset", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "FormContainer", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
<div id="ListOfAssestDiv">
        @Html.Action("Assets")
</div>
        </div>
        <div id="FormContainer">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Cool thanks. Just a small question, why are you adding the random parameter to the end of the assets url?

Comment: @DavidKethel . It's ajax request. In IE if the url is same than it will take the response from browser Cache (in debug mode) so to avoid this thing.

Comment: How would you do this in .net Core now that @Html.Action is not supported. From that I gather you cannot do ajax requests with View Components.