# How do I render a partial view as javascript string in aspnet mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following partial "InfoWindowContent" view.

```
    @model CasWeb.Models.ViewModels.AssetLocation
<div>
    <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Lat:
            </td>
            <td>@Model.Lat
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Lng:
            </td>
            <td>@Model.Lng
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And I would like to use this as the content of a google maps info window. So I have been thinking something like this

```
//Get the content for info window for this asset from a a partial view
            var infoWindowContent@(asset.Name) = "@Html.Action("InfoWindowContent", @asset)";

            var infoWindow@(asset.Name) = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: infoWindowContent@(asset.Name),
                maxWidth: 200
            });
```

The problem I have is that java script complains of having a un terminated string literal, as the @html.Action method returns the partial view with all the line breaks in it and I end up with java script code like:

```
var infoWindowContentd4444444 = "<div>
<h2>d4444444</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Lat:
        </td>
        <td>43
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Lng:
        </td>
        <td>43
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

";

I can get around this be removing all the line breaks from my partial view like:

```
    @model CasWeb.Models.ViewModels.AssetLocation
<div><h2>@Model.Name</h2><table><tr><td>Lat:</td><td>@Model.Lat</td></tr><tr><td>Lng:</td><td>@Model.Lng</td></tr></table></div>
```

But this is a pain, and hard to maintain.

Any ideas how I can render the partial view as java script string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you create a one more action and return PartialViewResult from the action. Made the Json request for this action and append the HTML response in the DIV. Please find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336349/how-do-i-refresh-html-action-from-a-controller/11338095#comment14957019_11338095).