# Using a $.get() in .Net MVC without a controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In .Net MVC if I'm using the JQuery `.get()` method to grab a file from the server would I still need to write up a `RenderAction` on a controller method to display its contents? Example JQuery:

```
function RenderPartialView(view, contentcontainer, maskcontainer, params) {
    $.get(view, params, function (data) {
        $("#" + contentcontainer).html(data);
        $(maskcontainer).unmask();
    });
}

   function displayExpandedView() {
       $('.expand-btn').on('click', function () {
           $(".expanded-view").modal();
           RenderPartialView("../some_dir/SomeView", "expanded-view", "#expanded-view", null);
       })
   }
```

So when I run the displayExpandedView() function I want to fill a div that is acting as a modal with the contents of the SomeView file. When I currently try to do this with in my application the server responds back with a 404 error saying the file cannot be found, even thought he path to it is correct. Using this method would I still need to have a controller return `PartialView()`? I was under the impression I would not.

Comment: What is the resource that `../some_dir/SomeView` points to? Is it a content file or is that a route?

Comment: What happens when you view '/some_dir/SomeView' directly on your browser?

Comment: It would be a .cshtml file.

Comment: `.cshtml` files require a controller to render them. You can't display a `.cshtml` file directly.

Comment: Ok thanks, I figured that is probably the case.

Comment: Your action could return a JsonResult, and the contents of that result could then be rendered in your div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that RenderPartial and RenderAction are server side code and are replaced by actual HTML whenever the page is delievered to the client.  If you look at the source of the resulting page, you'll see that the line `RenderPartialView("../some_dir/SomeView", "expanded-view", "#expanded-view", null);` would be replaced with the HTML rendered from that partial view, which would not be valid javascript in the context of that function.  I.e. if the partial review returned `<div>Something</div>` then that javascript function would become

```
function displayExpandedView() {
   $('.expand-btn').on('click', function () {
       $(".expanded-view").modal();
       <div>Something</div>
   })
```

and therefore not be valid javascript.

To retrieve a View from javascript, your Get should point to the url of an action:

Javascript makes a request to a controller action, which will retrieve HTML:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")', function(response) { 
  //URL could also be a regular relative url, so long as it reaches the controller action, note here agsain Url.Action is a server side action and is replaced by a URL when page is rendered.
  $('.result').html(response);//stuff the HTML returned into some element with class .result
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Action:

```
public ViewResult ActionName()
{
   return View("ViewName");
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you thought I was trying to do this or not but, the RenderPartialView function that I was using in the above example was my own function using Javascript. I wasn't trying to use server side code with in it.

Comment: @Stavros_S A 404 would indicate that `"../some_dir/SomeView"` probably isn't the correct URL for your action.  It wouldn't be the path to a View, it needs to be a URL that will be routed to your controller.  Have you put a breakpoint in your Controller Action to see if its being hit?  Try changing to `RenderPartialView('@Url.Action("SomeView")',` assuming that SomeView is the name of an action in the current controller.

Comment: Also just to be sure you understand, you can not perform a Get directly to a view/cshtml, it has to be to a controller action.

Comment: Url.Action isn't needed, as long as you get the URL of the action right, but since this helper will generate the URL for you, it can help eliminate an error you might make.

Comment: Yea I was under the impression initially (stupidly) that I could directly go to a cshtml page as if it were a standard html page.

Answer (score 1):

> Using this method would I still need to have a controller return PartialView()? I was under the impression I would not.

Yes, you would still need your controller to return your partial view. Remember, when you use ASP.NET's Render.PartialView, that is happening server-side so all the appropriate work is being done to generate the HTML. However, when you make the call using jQuery, you cannot access the HTML directly from the client like that (and if you could, it would not be good practice to). Instead, you need to make a call to your controller action (or a [content file](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/files,-images,-and-media/working-with-files)) to [receive back the HTML which you can then append to your DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11338095/132528).